# Optimizing Spark SQL Query for Data Aggregation

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to aggregate data from an Azure database using Spark SQL. The original way I saw someone else do it was like this:

```
select
max(Timestamp),
mean(datacolumn1),
median(datacolumn2),
max(datacolumn3)
from myTable where datacolumn2 = "Yes"
and Timestamp between "1684738800000000" and "1684825200000000"
GROUP BY FLOOR((Timestamp)/(N*U*1E6))*(N*U*1E6)
```

Where N = Numerical, integer multiplier against the aggregation type and U = The number of seconds in the aggregation type (ie. second = 1, minute = 60, hour = 3600, etc.). This should average the data within these groups, yet the issue I am seeing is that when I convert the timestamps locally, the are not correct and it's definitely a problem with the query but I don't know exactly what. So I tried rewriting it entirely:

```
WITH Aggregated AS (
    -- Filter data, convert timestamps, and aggregate in one step
    SELECT
        FLOOR(Timestamp / (1000000 * N * U)) * (N * U) AS grouped_timestamp,
        min(Timestamp) as min_timestamp,
        AVG(data1) AS data1,
        AVG(data2) AS data2,
        AVG(data3) AS data3
    FROM dataBaseTable
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN UNIXtstart AND UNIXtstop
    GROUP BY FLOOR(Timestamp / (1000000 * N * U))
)

SELECT
    grouped_timestamp,
    from_unixtime(CAST(grouped_timestamp / 1000000 AS BIGINT)) AS datetime_representation,
    data1,
    data2,
    data3
FROM Aggregated
ORDER BY grouped_timestamp;
```

Although it works very well, it is also extremely slow. About 120x slower which is not realistic because the data density is on the order of micro-seconds. So if I try to query data for timestamps on a monthly or even annual basis it ends up running through multi-billions of rows on the server. So I tried optimizing it by changing some things around:

```
WITH Aggregated AS (
    -- Filter data, convert timestamps, and aggregate in one step
    SELECT
        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Timestamp AS BIGINT) / (1000000 * N * U)) * (N * U) AS BIGINT) AS grouped_timestamp,
        MIN(Timestamp) as min_timestamp,
        AVG(data1) AS data1,
        AVG(data2) AS data2,
        AVG(data3) AS data3
    FROM dataBaseTable
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN UNIXtstart AND UNIXtstop
    GROUP BY FLOOR(CAST(Timestamp AS BIGINT) / (1000000 * N * U))
)

SELECT
    grouped_timestamp,
    from_unixtime(CAST(grouped_timestamp / 1000000 AS BIGINT)) AS datetime_representation,
    data1,
    data2,
    data3
FROM Aggregated
ORDER BY grouped_timestamp;
```

However, this produces incorrect timestamps (ie. -8741307600) which when I looked it up, meant an integer overflow possibly. I tried avoiding it by explicitly casting Timestamp as bigint, but this did not work. Even though this is last option is faster, I don't think it's doing the math correctly. The first option is ideal, but just not correct. Second option is correct but too slow. Is there a way to be able to get a correct and fast way of aggregating large data sets that contain billions of rows?

Note: UNIXtstart, UNIXtstop, N and U are all user inputs that change with each query. Here is a test matrix that mimics the data structures I am working with: https://dbfiddle.uk/JadOeVwF

PS - This is Spark SQL and there wasn't a tag I could find for it when I typed in spark or at least there may be a name that is different but means the same thing in tags. IDK

Answer (score 1):

I tried your query on your sample data in my environment, with `N` as 1 and `U` as 3600 for an hour.
Even I got the same results as you, the wrong timestamps.

[image]

But when I give `U`  35 (2100) minutes is working.

[image]

So, you can use below altered query for correct timestamps.

```
WITH Aggregated AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(floor(CAST(Timestamp  AS  BIGINT) /  1000000  /  N  /  U) * (N  *  U) AS  BIGINT) AS grouped_timestamp,
        MIN(Timestamp) as min_timestamp,
        AVG(data1) AS data1,
        AVG(data2) AS data2,
        AVG(data3) AS data3
        FROM sample1
        WHERE  Timestamp  BETWEEN  "1684738800000000"  and  "1684825200000000"
        GROUP  BY  FLOOR(CAST(Timestamp  AS  BIGINT) /  1000000  /  N /  U)
        )
        
SELECT
    grouped_timestamp,
    from_unixtime(CAST(grouped_timestamp AS  BIGINT)) AS datetime_representation,
    data1,
    data2,
    data3
FROM Aggregated
ORDER  BY grouped_timestamp;
```

Output:

[image]

Here, you can see I am getting aggregated values over 1 hour timeframe
and for 2 hour timeframe.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. I don't know why but I don't get notifications. I wanted to ask about your changes: Does SQL not conduct math in the proper algebraic sense? Because I don't understand why it works to keep dividing N and U from the floor like that unless SQL evaluates each operation individually from left to right. However, that also wouldn't make sense so I assume that the algebraic rules do not change and it leaves me to wonder why that works the way it does.